# Non-linear system of differential equation with stiff potential

Tags: nonlinear

I am trying a system of two differential equations that looks pretty simple, but with a potential varying a lot on a short period centered on 0. The definition of the potential followed by the attempt at solving the differential equation is

```
a0[y_] := 10^(-22) y^2/k^2 + Sqrt[1 + y^2/k^2]; 
a2[y_] := D[D[a0[y], y], y]; 
f[y_] := 10^(-18)* a2[y]/a0[y]^3; 
g[y_] := 1 + f[y]; 
pot[y_] := D[D [g[y], y], y]/g[y]; (* Potential *)

yi = -300;
yf = 100;
k = 10^(-20);
sol = NDSolve[{x1'[y] == (pot[y] - 1) - x1[y]^2 + x2[y]^2, 
x2'[y] == -2*x1[y]*x2[y], x1[yi] == 0, x2[yi] == -1} , {x1,x2}, {y, yi, yf}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]]
Plot[Evaluate[x1[y] /. sol], {y, yi, yf}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 500, AxesLabel -> {y, "x1(y)"}]
Plot[Evaluate[x2[y] /. sol], {y, yi, yf}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 500, AxesLabel -> {y, "x2(y)"}]
```

And it appears that the solutions $x1$ and $x2$ are just equal to the initial conditions. I was expecting something growing after 0, since the potential there is about $10^{40}$, but I can't even see a little deviation from the initial values. Any comment, any clue on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you need to transform your differential equation (substitutions) in order to get closer to a numerically solvable model.

Comment: If you change `a2[y]:=...` to `a2[y_] := Derivative[2][a0][y];` and `pot[y]:=...` to `pot[y_] := Derivative[2][g][y]/g[y]` the potential can be  evaluated and evaluates to `Ò[10^-68]`.  That might explain the behavior.

Comment: What I mean is that your `pot[y]` is so singular at `y=0` that you could simplify your differential equation dramatically by approximating `pot[y_] = q*DiracDelta[y]` (for some amplitude `q`) and trying to find an analytic solution of the differential equation. This analytic solution could then be used as a base to find the exact solution by appropriate transformations.

Comment: @Roman I tried what you suggested and, unsurprisingly, NDSolve encountered a step size effectively zero (for y around pi). I then tried to solve the system using DSolve with and without initial conditions, but the output MMA gave me was the input I gave. I am puzzled here...

Comment: @Free_ion for the Dirac $\delta$-suggestion you could solve the equations analytically, it may be easier than `NDSolve`. Are you familiar with the techniques for doing this in the presence of $\delta$-potentials? Essentially you solve the differential equation for $pot=0$ and then connect two different regions ($y<0$ and $y>0$) by a kink given by the $\delta$-function amplitude.

Comment: @Roman With **pot=0**, I got the following results for my functions: `x1[y] -> (300 + y)/(90001 + 600 y + y^2)`  and `1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[(89999 + 600 y + y^2)^2/(90001 + 600 y + y^2)^2])` . The first problem here is that the plot is peaked at y=-300, when it should have been 0.
Then, I tried to connect the two regions as you said using 
`sol1[y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(300 + y)/(90001 + 600 y + y^2), 
    yi <= y < 0 || 0 < y <= yf}, {10^(41)*DiracDelta[y], y == 0}}]`
but the potential doesn't seem to have any effect at all...

Comment: That's not what I meant by connecting them. You need to integrate the differential equations across the singularity to get rid of the Dirac-$\delta$. Maybe ask for more details at the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com), as I don't have the time to solve this right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate my comment:

```
Clear[a2, pot]
a2[y_] := Derivative[2][a0][y];
pot[y_] := Derivative[2][g][y]/g[y];(*Potential*)


Plot[pot[y], {y, yi, yf}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

and

```
Plot[pot[y], {y, yi, yf}, PlotRange -> All,PlotPoints -> {Automatic, {0}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the potential itself is well-defined, and is actually similar to this one [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190719/solving-a-system-of-linear-ode-with-stiff-potential), with different ranges in x and y. But changing the definition of the derivative does not give a different behaviour for x1 and x2, unfortunately.

Comment: The change from `D[..]`  to `Derivative[..]` changes a lot . Look at `pot[y]` in both versions. Only the second one can be evaluated/plotted!

Comment: But is this really an effect of using Derivative[..] instead of D[..]? It seems to me the only difference is in the number of points used to make the plot.

Comment: Try to evaluate ` pot[0]` and you'll get, expecting a number,  a strange result `\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\((1 + 
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]1\)\), \
\(1000000000000000000\)])\)\)\)/(1 + \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(0\)]1\)\)/1000000000000000000)` (sorry I don't know how to show the formated output...)

Comment: I guess I see your point. I always used to do `pot[y] /. y -> 0 // N `, with a number as output. But the output I get from NDSolve does not change whether I use one or the other definition for the derivative, _i.e._, I still get the same constant plots...